# Amplify DataStore query: Hub ready event triggered multiple times

Tags: vue.js, datastore, aws-amplify

I am using Amplify DataStore with a Vue app.

Everything works as intended except when I call clear() and start() and use the Hub to listen for the ready event.

On starting the app, I do some stuff and then update the syncExpression to configure the DataStore. I then call:

```
DataStore.clear()
DataStore.start()
```

to resync.

The hub event triggers once the store is ready. I then make a query request like this:

```
const result = await DataStore.query(Merchant, merchantId)
```

which returns the correct data.

However if I make another query request(using a different merchantId), after calling clear() and start(), the hub ready event is triggered twice. This happens for each subsequent query - the ready event is triggered incrementally (after clearing and starting the store).

So here's a summary:

- start app
- re-configure sync expression
- clear and start
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 1)
- do query passing merchantId = 1
- return result for merchantId = 1

then for the next query:

- re-configure sync expression
- clear and start
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 1)
- do query passing merchantId = 2
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 2)
- return result for merchantId = 1
- return result for merchantId = 2

the next query:

- re-configure sync expression
- clear and start
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 1)
- do query passing merchantId = 3
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 2)
- hub ready event triggered when ready (triggered 3)
- return result for merchantId = 1
- return result for merchantId = 2
- return result for merchantId = 3

next time ready event will be triggered 4 times
and so on....

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to trigger once only for each query?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working out the kinks in my Datastore usage so I don't have a full answer.
I do have a suggestion, and that is to change the call to `Datastore.clear` to `DataStore.stop`. You can't change the sync expression when Datastore is running so you stop it and restart it after changing the sync expression. That way you don't remove all the previously synced local data.

Comment: hi @julie, thanks for your answer. my problem is that i have to clear the database but i take your point that i have to first stop it - i am not sure if clear actually does the stop and then clear, will investigate that. thanks again